# React native async/wait not waiting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am new to react-native. I am trying to use async/await but it doesn't wait for other function  to return response and alert immediately it will not wait 4 seconds. Here is my code Please help me. Thanks in advance:

```
import {
  AsyncStorage,
  Platform
} from 'react-native';


export const  hello =async()=>{
 const value=await refreshToken();
 alert(value);
 return "adasd";
}


const refreshToken=async()=>{
  setTimeout(async()=>{
    return true;
  },4000);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `await` can only be done on a `Promise`, and since `setTimeout` doesn't return a `Promise` you cannot await it.
To do the same thing you are trying now, you would have to explicitly use a `Promise` like so:

```
export const  hello =async()=>{
    const value = await refreshToken();
    alert(value);
    return "adasd";
}

const refreshToken= () => {
    return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 4000));
}
```

Comment: Actually any `async` function returns a promise.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @str That's true, but you cannot resolve that promise with setTimeout since it doesn't return a Promise you can await.